# System.Exception {System.ArgumentException} Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: windows-phone-8, toolkit, listpicker

I'm getting this exception whenever i try to access m list picker control in my app.

```
+       this    {App_name.App}  App_name.App
+       sender  {App_name.App}  object {App_name.App}
-       e   {System.Windows.ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs} System.Windows.ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs
+       base    {System.Windows.ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs} System.EventArgs {System.Windows.ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs}
+       ExceptionObject {System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.}  System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}
        Handled false   bool
+       Non-Public members
```

Code for my list picker is

```
<ListBox Margin="0,417,0,0">
            <ListBoxItem>
                <toolkit:ListPicker Name="LearnerFileChooser" Width="431" >
                    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="A" />
                    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="B" />
                    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="C" />
                    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="E" />
                    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="F" />
                    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="G" />
                    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="H" />
                </toolkit:ListPicker>
            </ListBoxItem>
```

If i reduce the no. of items to 4 then it works properly but it crashes on more then 4 items.

I'm trying to create a list of alphabets from which user can choose.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone Toolkit ListPicker Throws an Unhandled Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17065970/windows-phone-toolkit-listpicker-throws-an-unhandled-exception)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known issue.

You must bind the items to be able to use more than 5.

[Explanation on Codeplex](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/9412):

> ListPicker as an ItemsControl, gets its Items property set to a list
>   of ListPickerItems in your example. ListPickerItems are UIElements,
>   and the ListPicker renders them in its presenter. When there are 5 or
>   less items, the expanded mode opens on the current page, and you can
>   see all the items in the presenter.
>
> But when 6 or more items are present, opening the list picker goes to
>   full mode which opens a new page. This new page has a listbox, which
>   gets its items property set to the listpicker's items. This is where
>   it breaks. By setting the listbox's items to the listpicker's items
>   (in this case a list of listpickeritems), the listbox will put those
>   UIElements into its view. Now a single listboxitem is included in two
>   places on the visual tree.
>
> Because of this issue, ListPicker only supports databinding and
>   templating. DO NOT set the ListPicker's items to specific UIElements.